# Jar files can't be found when running mapreduce job on jarn

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm trying to run a mapreduce job on yarn.
When I run it locally, it has information like this:

> 2015-08-24T11:55:26 INFO main mapred.LocalDistributedCacheManager: Localized
>   file:/data/yany/project/hbase-oss/target/hbase-oss-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
>   as
>   file:/tmp/hadoop-yany/mapred/local/1440442525965/hbase-oss-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

But when I set

```
hBaseConfig.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn");
```

and gave some yarn parameters

```
hBaseConfig.addResource("yarn_site.xml");
```

The job starts on yarn, but finally failed with error message:

```
2015-08-24T12:32:19 INFO main impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1432167711015_0030
2015-08-24T12:32:19 INFO main mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://somelink.com:8088/proxy/application_1432167711015_0030/
2015-08-24T12:32:19 INFO main mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1432167711015_0030
2015-08-24T12:32:22 INFO main mapreduce.Job: Job job_1432167711015_0030 running in uber mode : false
2015-08-24T12:32:22 INFO main mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
2015-08-24T12:32:22 INFO main mapreduce.Job: Job job_1432167711015_0030 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1432167711015_0030 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1432167711015_0030_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://somelink.com:8088/proxy/application_1432167711015_0030/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/data/yany/project/hbase-oss/target/hbase-oss-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar does not exist
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

Comment: can you please add command you are using to run the job

Comment: Im working on a large repo and we have our own interface to run the copy thing. Here is my command: tools/target/tools-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar ops -X copy-table --hbasecluster=hbase020 --application=queries --query=query_count --fromtable=shared_storage --totable=test_copy --since=2015-07-01T10:00:00-0800 --till=2015-07-02T10:00:00-0800 --hbase-plugins=hbase-oss/target/hbase-oss-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar